# How to avoid passing in several arguments to factory method?

Tags: c#, factory

Suppose I have 3 classes: A, B, and C (removing a lot of details from the real code here to simplify things) that contain a factory method which creates an object that derives from interface D (this is pseudo code by the way):

```
public abstract class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }

    public abstract D CreateD(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    : base()
    {
    }

    public D CreateD(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)
    {
       return new E(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    private bool someFlag;

    public C(bool someFlag)
    : base()
    {
        this.someFlag = someFlag;
    }

    public D CreateD(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)
    {
        if (this.someFlag)
        {
            return new F(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
        }
        else
        {
            return new G(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is avoid having to pass in all of the arguments in the CreateD() methods. I also want to avoid having class A contain references to those objects (as there may be many instances of A). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Create little classes or structs whose sole purpose is to pass the required construction arguments.  Or perhaps replace some of them with properties on an interface that you set after it is constructed.  Avoid over-engineering it, note how the .NET Framework can get its job done without a lot of factories.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Using a Builder pattern you will build objects by composition. For example (from Wikipedia):

```
CarBuilder builder = new CarBuilder();

builder.SetColour("Red");
builder.SetWheels(4);

Car car = builder.GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class or structure containing arguments arg1-arg6. That way you have only one parameter. Review you code if you really need six parameters; that could indicate a situation that the class does too much.

Comment: I thought about that, but a lot of the arguments are factories themselves. Maybe it's not a big deal. It just seems like there may be a creational pattern I could use instead.